# Better control to use for XAML than a grid with many rows

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamarin

If you want to organize a XAML page that has a grid with many rows, and find yourself constantly needing to make adjustments to the page as you are developing it seems kind of inefficient. For example needing to change attributes on each control after an insertion from row="40" to row="41" and so on down the line after an insertion at the top. Grid seems to be the best control I have found for having control over the layout, but there are other controls out there. What is the best control to use in this type of situation with many rows and several columns?

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Comment: If all rows height are set to `Auto`, you could use a `DockPanel` or `StackPanel`

Comment: And if your rows are dynamic an itemscontrol with the rows templated out from row viewmodels is another thing to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A perfect replacement for a Grid with only `Auto` rows would be a StackPanel:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="Row 1"/>
    ...
    <TextBlock Text="Row N"/>
<StackPanel>
```

In case of a Grid with only rows with `Height="*"`, it would be a UniformGrid:

```
<UniformGrid Columns="1">
    <TextBlock Text="Row 1"/>
    ...
    <TextBlock Text="Row N"/>
</UniformGrid>
```